# Play embedded video in UIWebView with HTML5

Tags: iphone, cocoa, html, ios5, uiwebview

I'm actually trying to play a local video into an UIWebView, with HTLM5.

What I do actually is this :

```
NSString *embedHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
<html><head>\
<style type=\"text/css\">\
body {\
background-color: transparent;\
color: white;\
}\
</style>\
</head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
< src=\"%@\"  \
</embed>\
</body></html>", [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ash(1).mov" ofType:nil]];



[webView setOpaque:NO];
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, webView.frame.size.width, webView.frame.size.height];
[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

I have on my storyboard an UIWebView named webView with weak / nonatomic property

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
```

When I launch the app, nothing happen : the screen still white and no video is playing.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
NSString *embedHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><style></style></head><body><video src=\"%@ controls autoplay height=\"400 width=\"320></video><ul></body></html>",  [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ash(1)" ofType:@"mov"]];

[webView setOpaque:NO];
//NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, webView.frame.size.width,  webView.frame.size.height];
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ash(1)" ofType:@"mov"]];
[webView loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:url];
```

Refer more [this](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CGoQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fsafari%2Fdocumentation%2FAudioVideo%2FConceptual%2FUsing_HTML5_Audio_Video%2FUsing_HTML5_Audio_Video.pdf&ei=9lS2T6XaFMnOrQfs75nyBw&usg=AFQjCNGTllf153t5fQ517jtZg0m0p07tcQ) to how to play video using html5

Comment: The code above does exactly the same that what I did, just displaying a white screen :( I've already seen the link and it is really usefull for HTML5 itself but not really for use it through an UIWebView.

Comment: check edited answer and your [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ash(1)" ofType:@"mov"] is correct

Comment: Nothing change :( And yes, the path for the video is valide, I checked it with `NSLog(@"%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ash(1)" ofType:@"mov"]);` and it has returned   `2012-06-20 12:47:10.620 testVideoUIWebView[5440:707] /var/mobile/Applications/EC8114CF-C55C-4062-B7C5-25FA9DDFC9F0/testVideoUIWebView.app/ash(1).mov`

Answer (score 0):

just change base url as

```
NSString *videoPath =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"xxx" ofType:@"mov"];

NSString *htmlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<body> <video src=\"%@\" controls autoplay height=\"400\" width=\"300\" > </video> </body>", videoPath];

NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
[xwebview loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```