# MPMoviePlayerController starting image

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

In my app the instance of `MPMoviePlayerController` I created starts out as a black box, looking like this (because the video starts out black and fades in):

[image]

However I was envisioning something more user-friendly like this, with a thumbnail image, like the example below:

[image]

That's a mockup I created but videos in the cameral roll and videos sent in the Messages app use that play arrow. What class do I need to implement to use the stock iOS play arrow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like something for the `thumbnailImageAtTime:timeOption:` method of `MPMoviePlayerController`, you should pass in the time you want to retrieve a thumbnail for and use that image to display a `UIImageView` on top of the video.

Once you have your thumbnail you create a `UIImageView` and set the image to the thumbnail and make sure you set `userInteractionsEnabled` to `YES`. Make sure to set the frame of this image view to cover the movie player.

Now you can create a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on that image view which will trigger a method. This method then invokes the `play` method of your `MPMoviePlayerController` object.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [...]

    UIImage *thumbnail = [moviePlayer thumbnailImageAtTime:5.0 
                                                timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];

    UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:thumbnail];
    iv.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    iv.frame = moviePlayer.frame;
    [self.view addSubview:iv];
    [iv release];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [iv addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    [tap release];

    [...]
}


- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
    iv.hidden = YES;
    [moviePlayer play];
}
```

Please note if you want the play button then make a play button in Photoshop, and add this on top of the thumbnail image view, attach the gesture recognizer to that image view and make sure you hide both image views when you start playing your video.

You could use a `UIButton` otherwise with the image set to the play image, then you wouldn't need a `UIGestureRecognizer` at all.

Comment: What about the play arrow? Is that shown over the `UIImageView`? Also, how to I set the `UIImageView` to enable user interactions like you mentioned?

Comment: Yes, in your case it is. Your preview image is not the same.

Comment: You still haven't answered my question. How do I get the play arrow I gave an example of, nor have you mentioned how you can "set the image view to enable user interactions". All the thumbnail method does is grab an image, I have an image, that's not the problem. Please try again.

Comment: Hi, did you get what you wanted now? Did my example code work out for you?

Comment: It did I guess, but you say I have to use Photoshop to create the play arrow, that there is no iOS stock play arrow. Are you sure? Obviously I already created one of my own for this post, but I was hoping there was a stock iOS one, I know I've seen it. (Looks just like my mockup.)

Comment: Yes. The `MPMoviePlayerController` doesn't allow you to simply set a "start image" so you're forced to overlay one on top. Luckily enough you can start the video programatically by calling `play` on the `MPMoviePlayerController` object so no play button isn't game over. The consequence of overlaying an image is that you hide the play button. But you can always make your own and overlay it again on top of the start image. Not very convenient I know. But usually if you're looking to make it nice with a start image you're in for the customisation so making the play button isn't that big a deal.

Comment: This does work .. but I am getting the image size really very small. 
Why so ?

Comment: Possibly non retina size on a retina screen?

Comment: When I use the  UIImage *thumbnail = [moviePlayer thumbnailImageAtTime:5.0 
                                                timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];  method , my video starts playing automatically ... can anyone suggest how to display the static image and play the video only when i press the play button

Comment: 'moviePlayer.frame' - "Property 'frame' not found on object of type 'MPMoviePlayerViewController *'"

Comment: I also hope the answerer and the OP @inorganik could do a follow-up on clearing some of the questions here in comments and how did they finally solve the arrow image etc, so that others could solve their problem like me with the help.

Comment: @Unheilig I created a UIButton with the same frame as the video. Then I set a background image of the button using an image I created by overlaying a play arrow over the first frame of the video. Then I simply hid the button when the video started playing.

Comment: @inorganik Thanks. I will go ahead and try it. +1 for your answer (however, on your question).

Answer (score 0):

You will get this arrow by embedding your video into an HTML 5 `<video>` tag in a web view.

For an actual implementation, see answers like this one [Play embedded video in UIWebView with HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115937/play-embedded-video-in-uiwebview-with-html5).

Answer (score 0):

What about just using an UIButton ? It can have a nice background image, click on it, and move it behind the movie player or remove the button even. So simple to add even in code