# UIWebview launch quicktime player when i try to load Video URL

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, video, uiwebview

I got one problem while playing video in `UIWebView`.

I got video url from Web-Service and i am playing that URL in `UIWebview`.
But the problem is `UIWebview` launches quick time player and video appears in full screen.

I want to display video in fixed `UIWebview` size.

But `UIWebview` open the video in quick time player in fullscreen.

I don't want to play video using `MPMoviePlayerController`

I want to display video like vine app.

Below is my code.

```
    UIWebView *webMove = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 305, 306)];
    webMove.delegate = self;
    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"demo" ofType:@"html"];
    NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [webMove loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
    webMove.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:webMove];
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at using the HTML5 Video Tag?

Comment: No, can you show me some code related to that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115937/play-embedded-video-in-uiwebview-with-html5