# How to play an embedded video in UIWebView?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiwebview

I need to play videos from Youtube, Facebook and Twitter.

I am using [XCDYouTubeKit](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit) to play youtube videos. For Facebook, I am using  UIWebview to load videos using below URL:

https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=1014684901996691

How do I play and pause that video programmatically (manually)?

i have tried

```
webvw_video.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.getElementById('movie_player').playVideo()")
```

Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880101/how-to-embed-youtube-video-on-ios-and-play-it-directly-on-uiwebview-without-full or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42831395/how-to-play-an-embedded-video-in-uiwebview or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115937/play-embedded-video-in-uiwebview-with-html5

Comment: these link are working only for YouTube videos, but mine in facebook videos